# Is a question regarding potential system design on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I had a question to propose a design for a potential computer system architecture and I was curious on caveats / potential issues within in, but I'm *not* quite sure if it fits here. Based on the help center I've seen:

> Computer science, also sometimes called computing science, is the science of computation and its applications. This site covers theoretical and applied computer science at any level, including but not limited to:
>
> - algorithms, models of computation
> - **programming language semantics, formal methods**
> - **computer architecture**, networks
> - machine learning, artificial intelligence, knowledge representation, natural language processing
> - vision, graphics
>
> The following topics are usually not suitable for this site:
>
> - Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they're homework from a class in a computer science curriculum. You may ask on Stack Overflow.
> - Questions about how a **particular piece of software or hardware works aren't science** (unless you're asking about the scientific concepts behind that software or hardware). You may ask on Super User or other appropriate technology sites.
> - Questions about numerical computation are often more appropriate for Computational Science Stack Exchange.

(Emphasis mine)

Now, to the first two bolded points: the question would involve a *slight* discussion on a programming language semantics and design, as it's regarding the embedding of a programming language within itself (think assembly but a little more abstract), it would also **almost entirely** revolve around the architecture design itself (mostly taking a nod at x86 / x64 for a base).

The third: the question would talk about a theoretical piece of hardware.

Next, from another section of the help area:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, **hypothetical question**: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”
>     (The above section was adapted from MetaFilter’s FAQ.)
>
> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that **explain “why” and “how”**
> - tend to have **long, not short, answers**
> - have a **constructive, fair, and impartial tone**
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with **facts and references**
> - are more than just mindless social fun

The points I'm concerned about I've emboldened once again.

Would a question that meets this criteria be, in fact, on-topic? If you would like me to add portions of what the question itself would be, I will gladly do so for an actual hardened example.

Comment: Based on the very first sentence it seems that you have some design prepared and want to get feedback about it, so it is a bit too broad and not well specified question - as you have mentioned it will start more of a discussion and that is not very well fitting to Q&A format.

Comment: @Evil What if the question is about the potential technical hurdles/caveats of *one specific area* or aspect of the design?

Comment: Then I think it is perfectly fine, if you can narrow it down, avoid discussions then it starts to fit.

Comment: @Evil Yes, it's only one specific area I want to ask about, I'm mostly concerned about two things: potential hurdles, and whether or not it would be beneficial.

Comment: There is a possibility that it will end up being too broad, so maybe more concrete example would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to ask, so I'll give some guidelines.

- You need to ask a specific, focused question.  "Here's my design, do you have any feedback?" probably isn't a great fit for our site format.  An open-ended request for caveats, pitfalls,  or potential issues in your specific design probably isn't a great fit.
- This site isn't for discussion, so a request for discussion or open-ended call for reactions won't be suitable.
- Try to make your question useful for others.
- Our site is for concepts, algorithms, ideas, science, etc., in the area of computer science.  If it's about gates and circuits, it's probably off-topic here.  However, computer architecture *is* on-topic.

Hope this helps.  If it's still unclear to you, tell us more about what you want to ask -- or better yet, just give it a try and ask your question on the main site, and I'm sure folks will be happy to offer feedback.